# Can multiple listeners be used in a cog?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Problem

I wanted to use multiple listener in a cog file in discord.py but it wont work. Only the last listener in the code gets called. How to solve it?

Code

```
class test(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # code of this function

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # code of this function

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(test(bot))
```

Comment: Why you should use same listeners? Can you just put all code in one listener or use another cog?

Comment: Yes i can use another cog but I dont think putting everything in same listener will be good for me. I just wanna know if there is any way to solve the above problem or another cog is the only option

Comment: You cannot have 2 of the same listener in one cog, but you can have one `on_message` listener in one cog and another `on_message` listener in another cog.

Comment: This is not multiple listeners, this is multiple listeners for the same event. This is how Python classes are designed - methods (functions) are first-class attributes and therefore you define it twice, is like putting this: `a = 5`  `a = 7`. The second time you redefine the variable `a`, it gets assigned value 7. This is also the case here, the last listener gets called and its intentional. Having multiple `on_message` listeners is bad practice anyway. You may still have different listeners under the same cog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cog%20listener#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener

```
class test(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def listener_one(self, message):
        # code of this function

    @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def listener_two(self, message):
        # code of this function

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(test(bot))
```